# Identify matching strings for group data and create new column that specifies presence or absence of change

Tags: r, match

Let's say I have the following dataset:

```
dat<- data.frame(ID= c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B", "B", "B"), 
             test= rep(c("pre","post"),5),
             item= c(rep("item1",2), rep("item2",2), rep("item3", 2), rep("item1",2), rep("item2",2)),
             answer= c("science","science","science","","", "science", "some multi word string that is not science", "history", "", "social science"))
```

I want to identify a specific element of the strings in `answer` for each grouping of `ID` and `item`. I need to identify instances of `science` excluding, for example, entries/strings like `social science`. While `social science` includes the word `science` I am only interested in instances where `science` is by itself.

A new column will be created called `change_type`.

- The level `both` indicates if science was present in both levels of `test`,
- `pre` indicates `science` was only present in levels of `test` equal to `pre`
- `post` indicates `science` was only present in levels of `test` equal to `post`.

The output will look like this:

```
res<- data.frame(ID= c("A","A","A","B","B"), 
             item= c("item1","item2","item3","item1","item2"),
             change_type=c("both","pre", "post", "NA", "NA"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do it with `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(ID, item) %>% 
  mutate(change_type = case_when(first(answer)=="science" & 
                                   last(answer)=="science"    ~ "both",
                                 first(answer)=="science" & first(test) == "pre" ~ "pre",
                                 last(answer) == "science" & last(test) == "post" ~ "post"
                                 )) %>% 
  group_by(ID, item,change_type) %>% 
  summarise()
```

```
  ID    item  change_type
  <chr> <chr> <chr>      
1 A     item1 both       
2 A     item2 pre        
3 A     item3 post       
4 B     item1 NA         
5 B     item2 NA
```